# How to create datetime index from string in python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, datetime

There are three files with names: `file_2018-01-01_01_temp.tif`, `file_2018-01-01_02_temp.tif` and `file_2018-01-01_03_temp.tif`. I want to list them names as `['2018010101', '2018010102', '2018010103']` in python.
The below code create an incorrect list.

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
from os import path

pattern = '*.tif'
filenames = [path.basename(x) for x in glob(pattern)]
pd.DatetimeIndex([pd.Timestamp(f[5:9]) for f in filenames])
```

Result:
`DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2018-01-01']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think simpliest is indexing with replace in list comprehension:

```
a = [f[5:18].replace('_','').replace('-','') for f in filenames]
print (a)
['2018010101', '2018010102', '2018010103']
```

Similar with [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
a = pd.Index([f[5:18] for f in filenames]).str.replace('\-|_', '')
print (a)
Index(['2018010101', '2018010102', '2018010103'], dtype='object')
```

Or convert values to `DatetimeIndex` and then use [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
a = pd.to_datetime([f[5:18] for f in filenames], format='%Y-%m-%d_%H').strftime('%Y%m%d%H')
print (a)
Index(['2018010101', '2018010102', '2018010103'], dtype='object')
```

EDIT:

> dtype is in object, but it must be in dtype='datetime64[ns]

If need datetimes, then formating has to be default, not possible change it:

```
d = pd.to_datetime([f[5:18] for f in filenames], format='%Y-%m-%d_%H')
print (d)
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01 01:00:00', '2018-01-01 02:00:00',
               '2018-01-01 03:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, dtype is in `object`, but it must be in `dtype='datetime64[ns]`.